# use Gnuplot to many files at once

Tags: file, loops, graph, gnuplot, zsh

I have many csv files that should be displayed each one in many graphs :

```html
data1.csv
data2.csv
data3.csv
data4.csv
data5.csv
.
.
.
dataN.csv
```

I am using a script to display only one chart for one file :

```
./script.sh data1.csv
```

How to generate graphs for all files at once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your script inside a loop

```
for file in $file_list; do
    ./script.sh $file
done
```

or, if you want all plots in one file then put this loop inside plot script (gnuplot 4.4+)

```
plot for [i=1:N] 'data'.i.'.csv' . . .
```

**EDIT**: If you want to pass filenames through command line args, wrap it in another script like this

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$@"; do
    [ -f $file ] && ./script.sh $file
done
```

Comment: for the second , Actually "data" is just an example , the files names are distincts

Comment: @Alexander Perhaps you can accept the answer if it solved your problem.